# SugarCRM - How to add an onClick event to existing HTML / Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, sugarcrm, suitecrm

SuiteCRM Version 7.2.1

Sugar Version 6.5.20 (Build 1001)

Okay so to be clear here, I know how to add an onClick event to a checkbox, the problem is that I am unsure how to do this specifically within SugarCRM.

I have a Multi-Select field in SugarCRM. It needed to be a Multi-checkbox, but HTML fields within SugarCRM are "Read-only". So I needed to edit the existing field and change it a Multi-checkbox. If found that answer [here](https://github.com/bickart/SugarCRM-CheckboxMultiEnum/blob/master/README.md).

Well, now I have a multi-checkbox such as below with a "none" option. What I want now to happen is in the EditView, when a user clicks "none of the above", all other options are disabled and un-checked.

Here is the normal code that's generated for the HTML:

```
<p style="height: 200px; overflow: scroll; margin-bottom: 1.5em; width:30%" class="select">
<input type="hidden" id="typesoflicenses_c_multiselect" name="typesoflicenses_c_multiselect" value="true">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="1" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Life Insurance</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="2" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Securities</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="3" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">CPA</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="4" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Attorney</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="5" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Mortgage Broker</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="6" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Real Estate</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="7" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">Enroller</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="typesoflicenses_c[]" value="8" id="typesoflicenses_c" title="">None</label><br>
</p>
```

So I need to add an onclick function to the "none" option and call a function. My problem is:

A) If I add a `'customCode' =>` option inside the `editviewdefs.php` file for that field, it will overwrite the entire field with whatever I put in there, and If I copy and paste the whole field html there, then nothing saves to the DetailView. I just simply want to append to the already existing html field.

Here is my javascript file:

```
//disable all other checkboxes if "none" is checked
function hideshowlicense(){ 

                                if (document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[7].checked){
                                //Disable checkboxes
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[0].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[1].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[2].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[3].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[4].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[5].disabled=true;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[6].disabled=true;
                                //Uncheck any other checked options
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[0].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[1].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[2].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[3].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[4].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[5].checked=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[6].checked=false;
                                }else{
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[0].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[1].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[2].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[3].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[4].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[5].disabled=false;
                                document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[6].disabled=false;
                                }

    }

    SUGAR.util.doWHEN("typeof($('#loa_c'))!= 'undefined'"), YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(YAHOO.util.Dom.get('loa_c'), 'change', dep);
    SUGAR.util.doWHEN("typeof($('#typesoflicenses_c'))!= 'undefined'"), YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(YAHOO.util.Dom.get('typesoflicenses_c'), 'change', hideshowlicense);
```

Right now I am getting an error in the chrome console and nothing is changed in the HTML. But if I pull up the same thing in firefox, no error is present.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149271/adding-custom-field-to-edit-view-sugarcrm?answertab=votes#tab-top) is also an article I read on modifying fields you've made changes too so that they retain there value in the detailview.

Comment: all your option have the same id. This is not a valid markup and probably is what is causing your error. Try to change the id to a class for all the elements and see if this fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in this before my javascript (the javascript listed above) and it fixed my issue. I had typed `doWHEN` instead of `doWhen`. I had some syntax errors.

```
SUGAR.util.doWhen("typeof($('#typesoflicenses_c'))!= 'undefined'",
        function() {
            YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(YAHOO.util.Dom.get(document.getElementsByName("typesoflicenses_c[]")[7]), 'change', hideshowlicense);
        }
    );
```

@[Lelio Faieta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399035/lelio-faieta), in this case, the HTML is being generated by Sugar, not me, and secondly the javascript can call by `name` instead of `id` using `document.getElementsByName`. -[W3 Schools, document.getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

`customCode` was also simply unnecessary in this case.

Credit to [Jeff Bickart](https://github.com/bickart) for helping through this via email. He was a major help.